# Value returned from overloading new and this do not match

Tags: c++, memory-management, this, new-operator

I have come across what I consider strangeness in my C++ code and am curious as to the cause.  I have overloaded new for class Object and print the returned value to the console. I also print the value of this in the constructor for Object.  These values do not match (they differ by one word).  Is this expected?

```
    void* Object::operator new(size_t size)
    {
        void* startAddress = ...
        std::cout << "object starts at absolute address " << (int)startAddress << "\n";
        return startAddress;
    }

    Object(TypeId type)
    {
        _type = type;
        std::cout << "this is address " << (int)this << "\n";

    }
```

Output:

```
object starts at absolute address 5164888
this is address 5164896
```

Comment: Can you show a minimal example that compiles, including the definition of `Object` and the code that invokes `new`?

Comment: How are you assigning `startAddress`?

Comment: @BitTickler is the definition of this the address of the first member or of the address of the start of any bits used to represent the instance?

Comment: @Dejas If there are any virtual functions, I think the relationship between `this` and the address of the members is implementation-dependent.

Comment: compiler dependent. Many do pointer to vtable at the start. But you cannot assume anything specific here.

Comment: @Barmar void* startAddress = CurrentHeapForThread->allocateForObject(size);  That method returns a void*.

Comment: depending on your compile type (debug, instrumentation etc), it could also be some very compiler specific thing... as in ... thing :)

Comment: So does this mean that the meaning of this is not controlled by the language specification but in fact is compiler dependent?

Comment: btw, you don't need the cast. `ostream` knows how to print most types of pointers (but not volatile pointers or function pointers)

Comment: It's not just that you don't _need_ the cast, the cast causes undefined behaviour on 64-bit platforms where `sizeof(void*) > sizeof(int)`

Comment: @Dejas, no, the meaning of `this` is determined by the language spec. The point is that the value you print in `operator new` is not the `this` pointer for any object, it's just an address at that point. The object gets created at a different address, after the compiler adds an offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new` is a raw allocator.  The use of the address and amount of memory requested is implementation defined.

As an example, debug information, or information about size of block (number of objects to destroy), or (maybe?  Tricky, not sure how arrays would work) vtable information can all be put before the "actual object starts".

Only trivially copiable objects are guaranteed to be copied via raw bits after `this`.

This means that the return value of placement `new` need be used, and not a reinterpreted pointer to raw storage, as an aside.